# PHPUnit running from phar not working

Tags: php, phpunit, phar

I need to run PHPUNit from PHAR instead of from Pear.
The only output I'm getting is the help file. I don't see my test run at all. Here is my code:

```
<?php
include 'phpunit.phar';
include 'phar://phpunit.phar/phpunit.php';

class ArrayTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{

    public function setUp(){ }
    public function tearDown(){ }


    public function testNewArrayIsEmpty()
    {
        // Create the Array fixture.
        $fixture = array();

        // Assert that the size of the Array fixture is 0.
        $this->assertEquals(0, sizeof($fixture));
    }

}
```

And I'm running it like this:

```
$ php index.php
```

thanks

<<**UPDATE**>>
After I ran this:

```
$ php phpunit.phar index.php
```

I got this error:

```
Class 'index' could not be found in '/home/ericp/public_html/dev/_test/phpunit/index.php'.
```

I fixed it by accident by adding "../" changing the path. I don't know why that fixed it, but it works. ***My index.php file is in the same directory as my phpunit.phar file***.
The working example looks like this:

```
<?php
include '../phpunit.phar';
include '../phar://phpunit.phar/phpunit.php';

class ArrayTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{

    public function setUp(){ }
    public function tearDown(){ }

    public function testNewArrayIsEmpty()
    {
        // Create the Array fixture.
        $fixture = array();

        // Assert that the size of the Array fixture is 0.
        $this->assertEquals(0, sizeof($fixture));
        $this->assertEmpty($fixture);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure about using the Phar of PHPUnit, but try the following on the command line:

```
php phpunit.phar index.php
```

I assume that PHPUnit is reading `$argv` to look up which tests to run.

Alternatively you may try creating a `phpunit.xml.dist` file in the directory, and running  simply `phpunit`, which should do it.

As said, I have no idea about Phars

Comment: Thank you. That worked to run it. But I ran into another problem that gave me this error: "Class 'index' could not be found in '/home/ericp/public_html/dev/_test/phpunit/index.php'.". I figured it out though and will update my question with the fix.

Comment: sry, forgot to mention. PHPUnit also expects that the contained class name matches the file name. try renaming the `index.php` to `ArrayTest.php`.

Comment: @EricP, What's the fix?